# Parse XML with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to  parse a xml with the below content

```
<File version="5.6">
<Parent name="A">
<Child name="a"/>
<Child name="b"/>
</Parent>

<Parent name="B">
<Child name="c"/>
<Child name="d"/>
</Parent>

<Parent name="C">
<Child name="e"/>
<Child name="f"/>
</Parent>

</File>
```

And I used the following code

```
for child in tree.getroot().findall('./Parent/Child')
     print child.attrib.get("name")
```

It just print all the name of children without the parent names.
Can I print the relevant parent name of each child like this?

```
A has a b
B has c d
C has e f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over parents, then find children of the parents.

```py
for parent in tree.findall('./Parent'):
    children = [child for child in parent.findall('./Child')]
    print '{} has {}'.format(parent.get('name'), ' '.join(c.get('name') for c in children))
```

**Response to the comment**

Using lxml, you can access parent node with [`getparent()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#getparent) method.

```
import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.parse('1.xml')
for child in tree.findall('./Parent/Child'):
    print '{} has {}'.format(child.getparent().get('name'), child.get('name'))
```

Comment: Can I iterate all the children and find their parent instead?

Comment: @JohnnyChen, You can, if you use lxml instead of xml.etree.ElementTree.